# Getting and storing user text input on the fly without save button

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

It is a web app.
The user type information in a Textarea box.
The information is stored in the localStorage.
Right now the user needs to click "OK" button in order to keep the information.
I would like that the information will be stored automatically.

What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: "Best" implies some criteria for evaluation, usually vs whatever it is you've tried (but not shown).

Comment: It is quite subjective. Most common way to go would be to send an ajax request on regular intervals e.g. every 60 seconds or 2 minutes etc. that saves this info on server. Or you can use websockets to push info to the server even faster.

Answer (score 1):

Without jQuery, we need to make sure that the text changes are captured for all (or most) of the browsers, so we can attach several listeners to the `textarea` element, updating local-storage, whenever the text changes.

```
function onTextChange(obj) {
   var elem = obj.target;

   // If text has changed, update local-storage and save the saved
   // value with the element for later checking w/o having to read 
   // from local-storage.
   if (elem.old_value !== elem.value) {
      elem.old_value = elem.value;
      window.localStorage.setItem("textEntry", elem.value);
      console.log('saved',elem.value);
   }
   return false;
} // onTextChange()

var elem=document.getElementById('textinput');
if (elem.addEventListener){
   elem.addEventListener('input',onTextChange.bind(elem),false)
   elem.addEventListener('keyup',onTextChange.bind(elem),false)
   elem.addEventListener('change',onTextChange.bind(elem),false)
}
else if (elem.attachEvent) {
   elem.attachEvent('onpropertychange', onTextChange.bind(elem))
}
```

More information about events which capture changes, see [keydown, keypress, keyup](https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html) and the example at [textInput event](http://help.dottoro.com/ljhiwalm.php).

Comment: Thank you. For the safe side of compatibility regardless of performance issues. Would it be better to use a 100ms timer checking if there is a change and saving it?

Comment: I do not know how a timer-delay would help. You do not know how quickly the person types. Since all the processing is happening locally, nothing is being burdened. In fact, I introduced unnecessary complexity by checking and saving the "old" value. I should've just saved the current value, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you store the data on the localstorage? IF yes, then you can update the localstorage content on every keypress on the textarea.

**Example**

```
$("#myTextarea").keypress(function(){
    window.localStorage.setItem("textAreaContent", $(this).val());
});
```